# Plot Previous Day's High, Low and Close in Pinescript for Forex and Crypto

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I used a combination of code from @carloswm85 and @vitruvius from a previous question on this same topic.

This code works perfectly for Bitcoin, it correctly plots the lines at the start of each session (7pm EST) and picks the previous day's values correctly (from between 7pm to 7pm).

But when I switch my chart to the USDCAD pair, the values appear to be correctly identified (between 5pm and 5pm EST from the previous day), however the lines get plotted starting at 12am EST, so there is a 7 hour delay in the plotting.

Is there a way to modify this code, so that it plots the lines at the correct times for both BTC and USDCAD?

To reiterate: Currently the code is correctly identifying the previous day's High, Low and Close for the USDCAD pair, but it's plotting these from 12am to 12am EST, instead of 5pm to 5pm EST.

Thank you kindly,
NCIC

```
//@version=5
indicator("Plotting PDR", overlay = true)

resolution = 'D'
var float highSecurityValue   = na
var float lowSecurityValue    = na
var float closeSecurityValue  = na

fNoRepainting(timeframe, expression) =>
    request.security(symbol = syminfo.tickerid, timeframe = timeframe, expression = expression[barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0], gaps = barmerge.gaps_off)[barstate.isrealtime ? 0 : 1]

trimLineAtRange = '0000-0001'
trimLinePlot = time('1', trimLineAtRange)
plottingCondition = not trimLinePlot


highRequest  = fNoRepainting(resolution, high)
lowRequest   = fNoRepainting(resolution, low)
closeRequest = fNoRepainting(resolution, close)
if trimLinePlot[1]
    highSecurityValue := highRequest
    lowSecurityValue := lowRequest
    closeSecurityValue := closeRequest

plot(plottingCondition ? highSecurityValue : na, title = 'H', style = plot.style_linebr, linewidth = 1, color = color.new(color.lime, 0))
plot(plottingCondition ? lowSecurityValue : na, title = 'L', style = plot.style_linebr, linewidth = 1, color = color.new(color.red, 0))
plot(plottingCondition ? closeSecurityValue : na, title = 'C', style = plot.style_linebr, linewidth = 1, color = color.new(color.orange, 0))

// Adding lines

// PDH = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"D",high)
// PDO = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"D",open)
// PDL = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"D",low)

var line l_pdh = na, var line l_pdo = na, var line l_pdl = na

// secondCoordinate = bar_index-1 + (1440 / timeframe.multiplier)

if barstate.islast
    l_pdh := line.new(bar_index-1, highSecurityValue, bar_index, highSecurityValue, extend = extend.right, color=color.lime)
    l_pdo := line.new(bar_index-1, closeSecurityValue, bar_index, closeSecurityValue, extend = extend.right, color=color.orange)
    l_pdl := line.new(bar_index-1, lowSecurityValue, bar_index, lowSecurityValue, extend = extend.right, color=color.red)

line.delete(l_pdh[1])
line.delete(l_pdo[1])
line.delete(l_pdl[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overcomplicating things.

`[_h, _l, _c] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", [high, low, close])` will return the `high`, `low` and `close` of previous day session. Then you can just use `plot` with it's default style in order to show them as lines on your chart:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

[_h, _l, _c] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", [high, low, close])

plot(_h, color = color.green)
plot(_l, color = color.red)
plot(_c, color = color.yellow)
```

Comment: Thanks, this code solves the issue with the USDCAD pair.

I want the lines to be drawn in full from the start of the day, not bar by bar as the day progresses, hence some of my "complicated code". I couldn't figure out how to get the lines to the correct length at the start of the session, so extending them rightwards was the best solution, as they automatically get trimmed at the end of the day.

Your code draws a long vertical line connecting the previous day's value to the new day's value, which clutters up the chart quite a bit. I'm sure there's a way to fix that, I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use style plot(_h, color = color.green, plot.style_circles)
This will solve your problem.